# How to pass data dynamically in custom helper codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

On my helper function I can pass data through index($data_info) using a variable

But I would not like to be able to add variable in function index() each time.

I am trying my make my function to be able to pass data dynamiclly like what codeigniter does with views.

**Example Current Way:**

Login Controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->helper('this_load_controller');

        $data['title'] = "Administration";

        $data['header'] = this_load_controller('common', 'header', 'index', $data);
        $data['footer'] = this_load_controller('common', 'footer', 'index');

        return $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Header Controller**

```
class Header extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($data) {

        // Should not have to do it like this header view should pick up automatic 
        return $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Header View**

```
<?php echo $title;?>
```

---

**Helper**

```
function this_load_controller($location = array(), $controller, $method = 'index', $vars = array()) {

    $path = APPPATH . 'controllers' .'/'. $location .'/'. $controller . '.php';

    require_once $path;

    $controller = new $controller();

    return $controller->$method($vars);
}
```

**Question** how is it possiable to pass data dynamicly with out add variable index($data_info) but still letting me have the option

Comment: in your Header Controller, why do you do this: `$data['title'] = $data_info['title'];` ? why cant you send it straight to the view like this: `return $this->load->view('header_view', $data_info);` ?

Comment: But I still have to have variable in index($data_info) each time which I do not want to have to do.

Comment: I do not want to have to add variable in index()

Comment: if you do not want to have to add variable in `index()`, how else are you suppose to pass data to your `index()` function? I believe theres no other way.